# How to make async methods that return a boolean?

Tags: java, android, loopj

I have the following method:

```
     public static boolean getIsUp()
     {
         String method = "isup.php";
         AsyncHttpResponseHandler response = new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){

         @Override
             public void onSuccess(String content) {
            if(Integer.parseInt(content) == IS_UP_CONTENT)
                //code to return true
            else
                //code to return false
        }

     };
     get(method, null, response);
 }
```

How would you fill the //code to return true and //code to return false so that the method return the appropriate response? Is that even possible?

Comment: Before you continue, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: And on top of reading that... instead of `if (condition) else` and writing what will be nearly identical code twice... why don't you just return what the (correct) comparison will evaluate to?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ooops, there was supposed to be an Integer.parseInt(content) instead of just content.

Comment: Do you have to use `AsyncHttpResponseHandler`. Does it provide a callback mechanism? Can you instead use a `ScheduledExecutorService` and block on the returned `Future`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am using loopj's AsyncHttpClient and it uses the AsyncHttpResponseHandler. I just took a look at the ScheduledExecutorService, and it seems like a hacky solution. But maybe that is because I am a C# developer and we are just used to the async and await keywords that basically does all this for you.

Comment: That's what `Future.get()` does. It waits until the `Callable` you submit to the `ExecutorService` has finished and returned a value. Maybe `loopj` has corresponding behavior. I've never used it.

Comment: Hmmm. I'l make sure to look into that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use an `AsyncHttpResponseHandler` inside a **non-async** method if you want to instantly return an result.

What you can do is using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and the `onPostExecute` Callback

> This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.